# O que esta errado com meu código? Ele fica dando erro "[Error] ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c

Obter um valor qualquer e perguntar ao usuário se este valor é em dólares ou em reais. 
Caso sejam dólares, convertê-los para reais. Se forem reais, convertê-los para dólares. 
Repetir a operação até que a soma dos valores informados seja maior do que 10.000,00.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

    int main(){

        float x,dr, xf, xs=0;//numero inserido, dolar ou real, numero convertido, conversao somada
        while(xs<=10000){

            printf("Digite o valor");
            scanf("%f",x);

            printf("Digite 1 para converter para dolar, e 2 para converter para real");
            scanf("%f",dr);

            if (dr=1) {
                xf=x*3.58;
                prinft("O valor em dolar e %.2f",x);
            }

            if (dr=2){
                xf=x/3.58;
                printf("O valor em reais e %.2f",x);
            }

            xs=xs+xf;
        }
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Na função `scanf()` o segundo parâmetro e o endereço da memória de sua variável, você deve informar o endereço utilizando o `&`, veja: `scanf("%f", &dr);`.

Comment: Cara, mudei isso mas ainda da o msm erro :/

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O segundo parâmetro da função `scanf()` ([consulte a documentação dela](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)) é o endereço de memória de onde esta armazenado o valor da sua variável, para obter o endereço dela utiliza-se o `&` comercial.

Veja seu código modificado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

    float x = 0, dr = 0, xf = 0, xs=0;//numero inserido, dolar ou real, numero convertido, conversao somada

    while(xs<=10000){

        printf("\nDigite o valor");
        scanf("%f", &x); /*<----- Mudei aqui*/

        printf("\nDigite 1 para converter para dolar, e 2 para converter para real");
        scanf("%f", &dr)  /*<----- Mudei aqui*/;

        if (dr == 1) {  /*<----- Mudei aqui*/
            xf=x*3.58;
            printf("\nO valor em dolar e %.2f",x);  /*<----- Mudei aqui*/
        }

        if (dr == 2){  /*<----- Mudei aqui*/
            xf=x/3.58;
            printf("\nO valor em reais e %.2f",x);
        }

        xs=xs+xf;
    }

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Veja este warning (aviso):

> ...\resp.c|11|warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *',
>   but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]|

Ele indica que deve receber um `float *` que é o ponteiro, o local do conteúdo de sua variável passada no argumento, **procure habilitar todos os warnings do seu compilador**. Também havia um erro de digitação na função `printf()` você digitou `prinft()` assim seu programa não vai compilar, e na condição `if` você usou o `=` ao invés do `==` que é para comparações. Não tem necessidade de sua variável `dr` ser um `float` já que ela é só para definir a opção escolhida, você pode utilizar uma variável de tipo inteiro para isso.

Comment: vlw cara, deu certo agora. Mas so tem um problema, quando eu digito se quero converter para real ou para dolar, ele me responde os 2, em dolar e em real. vc sabe oq pode ser?

Comment: Nao percebi que vc usou o = ao inves do ==, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: editado a resposta.

Comment: ahh sim, obrigado cara. vlw mesmo kk. eh q estou comecando agora com isso, e eh um pouco confuso ainda kkk